# conditional anchor tag control

Tags: javascript, html

in html,

```
<a href="/shop/view-item.php" onclick="checklogin();">View Item</a>
```

As you know, the execution order is, 

1) onclick javascript function, checklogin,
2) go to href link, and page refresh, /shop/view-item.php

And if you add 'return false' in onclick function's foot, 
href doesn't work. so the page remain on the same page. The code is,

```
<a href="/shop/view-item.php" onclick="checklogin();return false;">View Item</a>
```

My question, 
Can I control 'return false' effect?
If user do not log, I want to user remain the same page with alert logging request.
If user logged already, let him go the anchor's link url.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure your `checklogin()` function will return true or false appropriately, then do the following:

```
<a href="/shop/view-item.php" onclick="return checklogin();">View Item</a>
```